# Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Cell coordinate can not be zero-length

Tags: php, excel, funciones, phpexcel

Al intentar crear una funcion que me rellene los datos automaticamente con PHPExcel y una serie de arreglos me salta el siguiente error:

> "**Fatal error:** Uncaught PHPExcel_Exception: Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\shared\PHPExcel\Cell.php:591 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\shared\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1218): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('') #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\shared\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1178): PHPExcel_Worksheet->createNewCell('') #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\shared\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php(1085): PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('') #3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\ALP009.php(266): PHPExcel_Worksheet->setCellValue(NULL, 'ID Tabla') #4 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\QA\shared\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 591"

Ya busque por varios lados y no doy con el error, ya actualicé mi version de PHPExcel ya que leí que ese error se daba en versiones anteriores.

Mi codigo:

```
  //Titulo de hoja ALP
    $tituloHojaAlp = array(
        'ID',
        'línea',
        'Modelo',
        'Submodelo',
        'Detalle1',
        'Detalle2',
        'Descripción',
        'Compra Web',
        'Formato',
        'Moneda',
        'Notas',
        'Orden',
        'Salto',
        'Alcance',
        'Amca',
        'Hmx'
    );
    function crearTitulos($objPHPExcel,$arrayTitulos){
    $columnasEx  = array('A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1','O1','P1','Q1','R1','S1',
        'T1','U1','V1','W1','X1','Y1','Z1');

    $long     = count($arrayTitulos);
    $conColum = count($columnasEx);
    //ALP

    for ($i = 0; $i < $long; $i++) {

        if ($long == $conColum) {
            break;
        } else {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($columnasEx[$i], $arrayTitulos[$i]);

            //  var_dump($columnasEx[$i].$d,$tituloHojaAlp[$i]);
             }
        }
     }
    //llamar la funcion y pasarle el arreglo
  crearTitulos($objPHPExcel,$tituloHojaAlp);
```

Comment: Y probaste imprimir lo que estás seteando, comentando la línea de PHPExcel y poniendo en cambio `echo 'CELDA: '.$columnasEx[$i] .' VALOR: '.$arrayTitulos[$i];`

Comment: También podría probar fijando el `ActiveSheet` una sola vez al inicio de la función `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);`,   y luego usando el que ya fijaste: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(...)`

Comment: @amenadiel  Ya probe haciendo lo que me dices con el "echo", para saber que me esta arrojando y si me muestra los datos, y pobre lo de asignar la hoja por default al inicio, y aun asi sigue arrojandome el mismo error. :(

Comment: Cuáles son tus celdas y títulos? porque el error te lo da con un título `'ID Tabla'` fue que no está en tu ejemplo

Comment: @amenadiel esa celda es de otra worksheet, donde inserto titulos también.     `//Titulo de hoja ALPT 
           $tituloHojaAlpt = array(
            'ID Tabla',
            'ID Registro',
            'Formato',
            'Accesorios',
            'Orden',
            'Salto',
            'Notas'
        );` Pero ese es de otro datasheet que no estoy usando la funcion